# How to print uint64_t properly in D language (dtrace)

Tags: printf, solaris, dtrace, uint64

I'm trying to `printf` some `Solaris` kernel level information with the type of `uint64_t` (e.g. `timestamp`) using a `DTrace` script. How I can print `uint64_t` safely and precisely in my `DTrace` code.

I know the proper way of printing `uint64_t` in C is:

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <sys/inttypes.h> //sys: Kernel level

uint64_t timestamp;
printf("%"PRIu64"\n", timestamp);
```

What's an equivalent in `DTrace` D? (`%d` and `%llu are imprecise and dangerous).

**NOTE** Not to be confused with other programming languages named "D" (a C++-like programming language developed by Walter Bright).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [DTrace Wiki: Output Formatting](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/DTrace/Output+Formatting):

> The D compiler does not require the use of size prefixes with printf format conversions.
>   The C printf routine requires that you indicate the size of arguments by adding prefixes such as %ld for long or %lld for long long.
>   The D compiler knows the size and type of your arguments, so these prefixes are not required in your D printf statements.

Moreover, the `%d` and `%i` formats in D will handle either signed or unsigned ints, so you can use any of `%d`, `%i`, or `%u` to print an unsigned integer value in base 10, all with the same results.

The OP asked in a comment about the `%Y` format. This can be used for a uint64_t value that contains the number of nanoseconds since the Jan 1 1970 epoch, e.g. the built-in [walltimestamp](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/DTrace/Variables#Variables-BuiltinVariables) variable. (`timestamp` and `vtimestamp` are *not* counted from that epoch.)

> The uint64_t argument is interpreted to be the number of nanoseconds since 00:00 Universal Coordinated Time, January 1, 1970, and is printed in the following cftime(3C) form: "%Y %a %b %e %T %Z."

Comment: Does it mean that I can safely `printf` a `uint64_t` variable using `%d` or I should print it via `%Y`?

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my answer to suggest which integer formats to use, as well as `%Y`.